# Export table to Excel using Laravel queue gives empty file

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel, laravel-queue

I have configured Laravel queue with horizon and everything is working perfectly, but when I start exporting the file, the horizon shows completed job while it gives me empty Excel file with 6kb in cache folder.

Here's my code:

`app/exports/FullReportExport.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Models\Admin\FullReport;

class FullReportExport implements FromQuery,  WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue
{
    use Exportable;

    public function query()
    {
        return FullReport::query();
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 5000;
    }
}
```

`app\http\FullReportController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Reports;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Exports\FullReportExport;

class FullReportController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    

    public function export()
    {
        (new FullReportExport)->store('invoices.xlsx');
    }
}
```

`worker.log`

```
[2023-09-20 04:05:10][10] Processing: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\QueueExport
[2023-09-20 04:05:10][10] Processed:  Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\QueueExport
```

`laravel-worker.ini`

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/bin/php /Users/cairocoder/Sites/localhost/myapp/artisan queue:work redis --timeout=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=cairocoder
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/Users/cairocoder/Sites/localhost/myapp/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Comment: In the examples , chunks works with ToModel impl.

Comment: @Mate even without chunks, it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you could verify the plain sql executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the return at the beginning of this statement

```
return (new FullReportExport)->store('invoices.xlsx')
```